# Почему на протяжении?

Tags: предлог

Пожалуйста, расскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что интересует? Почему это предлог или почему пишется -И? Это производный предлог, служащий для связи слов в словосочетании на основе управления.Предлог образовался из сочетания непроизводного предлога НА, требующего предложного падежа, и существительного ПРОТЯЖЕНИЕ в предложном падеже. Т.к. сущ. на -ИЕ, то в П.п.- окончание И, тогда как В ТЕЧЕНИЕ,В ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ,В ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ - предлог В требует Вин. пад.,поэтому окончание -Е(на чём - на протяжении, во что?- в течение)

Comment: Объяснение "от предлога" оставляет вопросы. Почему В требует Вин.п., когда может быть и "в течении реки"?

Answer (score 2):

Выбор окончания Е/И в производных предлогах - это выбор падежа исходного существительного.
К примеру, в трех производных предлогах со значением времени  В ТЕЧЕНИЕ, В ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ, НА ПРОТЯЖЕНИИ разное окончание Е/И соответствует В. или П. падежу входящего в его состав существительного.Объяснить это можно исходя из значений этих падежей.

В.п. имеет количественное значение: отрезок длиной в 1 метр, перерыв продолжительностью в 1 час. П.п. указывает на  место или время, не уточняя границ, и этим отличается от В.п.

Например: Работа будет закончена в (ТЕЧЕНИЕ ЧАСА), то есть за ЧАС (В.п.). Средняя скорость НА ПРОТЯЖЕНИИ всего пути равна 72 км/ч.(П.п.)

Также: В течение нескольких веков луга Сахары превратились в пустыню  из-за наклона оси Земли. На протяжении веков  мода имела разные направления.

Answer (score 1):

Протяжение – то, что протянуто, линейно: на протяжении долгих лет, на протяжении пути - отвечает на вопрос : на чём?